# Are Japanese-language anime scripts available on line?

Tags: resources

My Japanese language study group often complains about the original Japanese in anime being too difficult to understand on the grounds of it being spoken too fast or something.  I was wondering whether the original Japanese-language scripts for a given anime (say, Toradora) can be downloaded.  From this a vocabulary list could be prepared.

If I want to see the script for Kill Bill, it's here:

http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/k/kill-bill-script-transcript-uma.html

and The Outlaw Josie Wales is here:

https://www.scripts.com/script/the_outlaw_josey_wales_15436  (suboptimal, however)

Would anything like this exist for anime?  Nothing promising searching for とらドラ脚本

Comment: Possibly no due to potential legal issues. Related: [Is there any website providing script from mangas in textual format?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26377/2516)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any website providing script from mangas in textual format?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26377/is-there-any-website-providing-script-from-mangas-in-textual-format)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following searching for "learn japanese from anime".

https://nihongoshark.com/anime/

This describes, well, a similar learning method, where one can do things with a subtitle file (if available).

From there I found a link to

https://kitsunekko.net/

which has a reasonable selection of material.

Lastly, there is always text ripping using
https://ytmp3.cc/en13/
then
https://convertspeech.com/processing.php
(Disclosure: nothing to do with either of these, just tried them once)
You only get three free conversions (which I suppose can be subverted with multiple computers or multiple IP adresses).  It gets some things wrong and the reading level is not that good, but it's infinitely better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this page](https://transcribedanimescripts.tumblr.com/completedscripts) that has a few anime scripts. It's not a super complete list although, you can check them in:

- English
- English and Romaji
- English and Japanese
- Japanese

Toradora only has [2 episodes scripted](https://transcribedanimescripts.tumblr.com/post/662724597433663488/toradora-master-list) but, for example, Violet Evergarden has the whole series.